Why flutter powersync data insert is not working?
I am using Supabase and Powersync as backend in my flutter app. I am trying to insert data but it's not wrorking, even it's not giving any error response at all.
Here you go with my code:
Future<void> addTask(
      String title,
      String type,
      String description,
      BuildContext context,
      ) async {
    try {
      _isTaskAdding = true;
      notifyListeners();

      ResultSet response = await db.execute(
           '''INSERT INTO tasks(title, type, description) VALUES( ?, ?, ? )''',
          [
            title,
            type,
            description,
          ]);

      print('response $response');

    } catch (e) {
      CustomSnack.warningSnack(e.toString(), context);
    } finally {
      _isTaskAdding = false;
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }

Could anyone please help me to share what's the issue and how to fix?
Thanks in advance.

I don't see anything wrong, but there's not much to go on here. Do you have any details on how it's not working? Is the code getting to the print('response $response') step?
You may get better help by asking on the PowerSync Discord directly.
